# The physical file format of a C# project is .csproj file. Is it possible to extract the files contained within such file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, project

When creating a C# application (which is a project in Visual Studio), such as a C# console applicaiton, a .csproj file that corresponds to such C# C# application (which is a project in Visual Studio) is created.

According to What are [Visual Studio solutions & projects? - Visual Studio (Windows)](https://What%20are%20Visual%20Studio%20solutions%20&%20projects?%20-%20Visual%20Studio%20(Windows)%20(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/solutions-and-projects-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022))

> When you create an app or website in Visual Studio, you start with a project. In a logical sense, a project contains all files that are compiled into an executable, library, or website. Those files can include source code, icons, images, data files, and so on.

Seeing as how a C# project / .csproj file is a container for file(s) (relevant to such project), as stated in the above excerpt, is it possible to extract the file(s) stored within a .csproj file?

Comment: A csproj doesn't contain files. It merely has the build config. The code files are usually next to the csproj, or in folders. If you mean you want to parse the csproj and understand the build config, that's somewhat different, but the default file config is simply "all the .cs files under here", at least with new-style SDK projects

Comment: A project contains all the files in a *logical* sense, but the .csproj does not contain an actual list of those files except in the simplest case and using the old-style format. New-style projects implicitly contain all files in the folder that contains the file *unless* overridden, so you'd need to know how to process all those directives if they're present. If you need reliable access to the compile-time structure of a project, use Roslyn.

Comment: @MarcGravell I'm trying my best to understand what you mean... and yes you are correct when you say "The code files are usually next to the csproj, or in folders.".... However, when I open an existing  .csproj file. I can literally see the .cs files as well as all the other --- files in the such .csproj file...  in the solution explorer window. Which is why it is hard for to believe when you say "A csproj doesn't contain files."... if that was the case then why I am able to open and edit the C# source code files that came in the .csproj file that I opened in Visual Studio?

Comment: @MVPyro because the IDE is reading the csproj to figure out which files to show you. The files aren't in the csproj though; they're usually alongside, and as I say: the default these days (if not overridden) is "include all the .cs files". If you look at the properties for individual files in the IDE (press F4 if you're in Visual Studio), it will tell you where the actual file is.

Comment: @MarcGravell I see what you mean. It seems my knowledge of a .csproj file in terms of what it is and what a .csproj file does contain is lacking. Do you recomend any specific blog post, documentation, video that would help me better understand .csproj files?

Comment: Specifically concerning the things you said.

Comment: You can just load the csproj in a text editor and see what it contains. It isn't magic, but the MSBuild system that it drives is very complex. What are you actually trying to achieve/learn here?

Comment: Have you actually tried opening it in a text editor? You can parse it using standard XML libraries, such as XDocument